# How to put a string "title" before others lines until a new string "title". a recursive problem to solve with awk, sed, perl etc

Tags: bash, awk, sed, perl

I have a txt file with more than 1million lines with the next content (its a tab between Match_n and "cggggg"):

```
Sequence_1
Match_1 cggggg
Match_2 gggggc
Match_3 ggggcc
Match_4 cgggcc
Match_5 agggca
Match_6 agggta
Sequence_2
Match_1 tgggca
Match_2 aggggg
Match_3 gggggc
Match_4 ggggca
Sequence_3
Match_1 cggggt
Match_2 ggggtt
Match_3 tgggga
Match_4 ggggac
Match_5 cggggc
```

And I need the following format:

```
Sequence_1  Match_1 cggggg
Sequence_1  Match_2 gggggc
Sequence_1  Match_3 ggggcc
Sequence_1  Match_4 cgggcc
Sequence_1  Match_5 agggca
Sequence_1  Match_6 agggta
Sequence_2  Match_1 tgggca
Sequence_2  Match_2 aggggg
Sequence_2  Match_3 gggggc
Sequence_2  Match_4 ggggca
Sequence_3  Match_1 cggggt
Sequence_3  Match_2 ggggtt
Sequence_3  Match_3 tgggga
Sequence_3  Match_4 ggggac
Sequence_3  Match_5 cggggc
```

More info: there are 10.000 "Sequence_N" and every one has a variable quantity of "Match_n  cggggc"

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NF==1{seq=$0; next} {print seq, $0}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using sed, you could move each `Sequence` string encountered into hold space and then pull it back out:

```
sed -e '/^Sequence/{h;d;}' -e 'G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\t\1/' file
```

Some rearrangement is necessary to get the `Sequence` ahead of the `Match` - but that can be rolled into the substitution that is required anyhow to change the newline separator.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl we can do as shewn:

```
$ perl -nlE '
  /^Seq/ ? ($h=$_) : say("$h\t$_")
' file
```

And using sed:

```
$ sed -ne ':a
    /^Seq/{h;N;}
    /\nSeq/D
    s/\n/\t/p;g;$!ba
' file
```